# Deploy failed. Reason: The TDS connector is not the correct version.

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sitecore, sitecore7, tds

I am migrating from Visual Studio 2013 to Visual Studio 2015. I installed TDS and can build and create TDS packages just fine. Initially I had an error complaining about a Hedgehog services dll not present which went away by re-installing TDS.

Now, the only issue I have is when I try to deploy to my local. The build test passes just fine but the deploy option fails in the TDS project with the following error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\HedgehogDevelopment\SitecoreProject\v9.0\HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.targets(633,5): error : Deploy failed. Reason: The TDS connector is not the correct version.

Has anyone seen this error before and how do I fix it? I can still deploy locally to my folder since is all code changes and I can also create the packages but it would be really nice to have it all working.

Thanks

Comment: Did you install TDS for Visual Studio 2015? When you download TDS the zip inside includes installers for specific VS versions. If you've done that then right click on a TDS project and select "Install Sitecore Connector" to update it for the latest version.

Comment: I installed the right version (i re-installed just in case) and selected "Install Sitecore Connector" which succeded, but no luck.

Comment: @Ernesto, is it possible that you still have an older version of TDS for VS2013 installed? If so, please try uninstalling and using the same version for both VS2013 and VS2015.

Comment: In that case delete `_dev` folder from the deployed website and `HedgehogDevelopment.*.dll` from your bin directory and try installing again to force it.

Comment: Uninstalled all other versions and deleted the dev folder, restarted, install connector seems successful, but deploy doesn't work. Same message.

Comment: I would contact Hedgeheog support, they are very quick to respond usually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into this issue while having multiple versions of TDS installed on my machine. My VS2013 has one version (5.1.something) and my VS2015 had a newer version (5.1.something else). Even though there are separate installers, TDS uses only one folder in the MSBuild location for its core DLL (C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\HedgehogDevelopment\SitecoreProject\v9.0), so you can really only have one version.

The other common scenario is having the target site containing files from an older version of TDS. Removing the _DEV folder is part of it, but you also usually need to remove the DLL that TDS installs in the bin folder.

As others have mentioned, support at hhogdev.com are awesome people who respond very quickly, so dropping them a line is always a good approach!

Comment: Nice summary of the comments :)

Comment: After contacting support the pointed me out the fact that the build output showed a different tds version (5.1.25) than the tests for tds (5.1.24). Not sure why the tests didn't succeed. Installing 5.1.25 fixed my issue but didn't really figure out where is visual studio tds version being read from and where is it installing it in the website folder.

Comment: @jammykam: I aim to please! Though to be fair, when I responded, I believe there were only comments regarding the _dev folder. 

Ernesto, I'm glad you were able to figure out that it was different versions. You can find the 'shared' version that TDS uses in C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\HedgehogDevelopment\SitecoreProject\v9.0 (I'll add this to answer)

Comment: What are date/time stamps between friends :)

Comment: lol... indeed! Obviously, I should refresh the page before hitting enter :)